# Blender bpy.data.materials.append(mat) applies mat twice

Tags: python, blender

I came across something very weird. I am trying to apply a new material to an object. I have used a condition that appends the material to the object if the object has no slots. Here the part of my code:

```
def Run():

curr_object= Import(obj_list, obj_extension)

#It is possible that the object has no slot material, and Blender is gonna fuss. Hence this security measure:

if curr_object.data.materials:
    curr_object.data.materials[0]= CreateMaterial(diffuse_path, normal_path)

else:

    curr_object.data.materials.append(CreateMaterial(diffuse_path, normal_path))


Export(outputFolderPath, obj_name)
```

I came across an object which didn't have any slot, and thus went in the "else" function. When reimporting the object into Blender, I realised it had the material twice ! I really don't understand what could be causing this. Can someone help me?

[The two materials on the object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZZNs.png)

Thanks!